# Appropriate to delete "how to fix" answer to question "why's it broken"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

A user posted a question asking why some code was broken. I posted an answer illustrating a correct approach. The "why" has already been answered and accepted but that answer did not explain how to make the code work.

I think my answer contributed valuable information to anyone who has this issue and finds the question through a search. I certainly don't consider it "dangerously incorrect" so I was suprised to see it voted deleted.

Am I in the wrong to provide a general answer that is directly related to a narrow question?
Can I vote to undelete it?

[Getting len of large buffered channel blocks for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791949/getting-len-of-large-buffered-channel-blocks-for-loop)

Comment: I wonder where you got the quoted "dangerously incorrect" bit from. Is that written somewhere?

Comment: >Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Strange phrasing, but as you can see that is mentioned as a reason to **downvote**, not delete vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the deleted post in the current state is not suitable as an answer.

The currently linked post looks like:

> Not answering your question; but here's a more idiomatic approach
>
> ....some code here ....

The answer must provide an answer. A one-line summary linking to some existing answer is enough. Explicitly posting content that you know does not answer the question is not suitable.

In that particular case you can either post a real answer (adding "do ... as shown in..." could be ok) or simply add a comment with a link to the existing (or new self-answered) post that shows how to do implement whatever OP wanted. I'd go for the comment approach if I'd know a reasonable existing sample Stack Overflow answer or article somewhere else.

Comment: thank you i will ask the more general question and answer myself